# Numbers regex for stripping domain from email address

Tags: email, numbers

I have a field that contains email addresses, I want to use regex to strip everything before the @ symbol to give me just the domain e.g.

```
john@apple.com => apple.com
jill@apple.com => apple.com
```

How can I do this will a simple function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without regex, you can use this:

if A1 contains 'foo@sample.com' then in B1 you can place the following formula:

```
=RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND("@";A1))
```

Comment: OK that works, but is way off for example "jake.noble@blah.com" gives me "le@blah.com". The incorrect proceeding chars seem to vary a lot too.

Comment: You need to use `LEN` too like this `=RIGHT(K3,(LEN(K3) - SEARCH("@",K3)))` - thank you so much!

Comment: Arrg, yeah sorry (made one simple example, and that worked fine), but your right! I updated the answer, so i thank you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If all that is in the field is an email address and you don't have to worry about validation, then `.+@` will match everything up to the domain name. if you need a search and replace, then use the same search string and leave the replace "expression" empty. That should replace what is matched with nothing.

Comment: Whats the Numbers Regex function - there doesn't appear to be one!?!

Comment: I don't know if Numbers has one. If it doesn't, then you will need to export to CSV and the problem of removing what you want from the email address becomes much harder.